# How to get the copyright string of a website

Tags: regex, go, web-scraping

I am trying to build a program in golang to check if a list of domain belongs to an organization or not by checking the copyright tag of the site For example if you go to sony.com then you will see `Copyright 2021 Sony Group Corporation` in the bottom of the page similarly if you go to tesla.com you will see `Tesla © 2021`. I am also using whois to verify and this is the other one.

I have tried most of the regex including one here [Regex to match copyright statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227295/regex-to-match-copyright-statements) but they don't seem to work.

This is the full code regex is what i am finding right now.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    domain := "sony.com"
    url := "http://" + domain

    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // reads html as a slice of bytes
    html, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // it will find the substring from html data
    r, _ := regexp.Compile("20[1-3][1-3]")
    if r.FindString(string(html)) != "" {
        fmt.Println(r.FindString(string(html)))
    }

}
```

This will only give output as `2021`. I am trying to achieve a Whole statement by which I can get the company name atlest.

Comment: This really needs more details. If you want to find the web sites of just `sony.com` you might not even need a regex; a static string match might be enough. On the other hand, if you require a general solution, you will need much more than a single regex to cover all the myriad ways in which HTML + CSS + Javascript can be used to render a copyright string somehow. Unfortunately, `whois` is also increasingly unreliable, as domain registrars are doing more and more to obfuscate domain ownership.

Comment: Looking for general solution, I was just testing with Sony.com will make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all reliable for any website but you can try this and optionally add some other cases of copyright starting string:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    domain := "sony.com"
    url := "http://" + domain

    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // reads html as a slice of bytes
    html, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    re, err := regexp.Compile(`>.*(&copy;|Copyright).*20\d\d.*</`)
    a := re.FindAll(html, -1)
    for _, j := range a {
        fmt.Println(string(j))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. this one only seems to work for sony.com